# extension=php_intl.dll in my linux centos doesn't exists

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos

I have a problem, I just want to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in my php.ini file
but that extension doesn't exist, I'm using Centos with Nginx configuration.

[image: This is my screenshot]

Comment: try apt-get install php7.0-intl

Comment: I'm using php 5.6.3
and i do that but not workin

Comment: try sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl, restart nginx

Comment: Well, .dll is windows stuff. you should be looking for some intl.so or php_intl.so.

Comment: apt-get is only for debian / ubuntu, not for CentOS which use yum.

Answer (score 0):

Linux servers don't use .dll files. You need a .so instead.

To install php_intl on CentOS , you should enable remi repo . Open the terminal and run the following commands:

> wget https://rhel7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
>
> sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm

Update your system then install the php-intl:

> sudo yum update
> sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl

To permanently enable remi repo , open the terminal and run the following command:

> sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
> Set enabled=1.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install PHP ?

PHP 5.6.3 is terribly old, and affected by tons of security issues, latest version is 5.6.40 but have reached its [end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) a few months ago

If installed from sources, you have to rebuild it, location of php command usually gives useful information (ex, when installed in /usr/local)

```
which php
```

or remove this build from sources, and switch to RPM provided binaries.

If installed from a 3rd party repository, you should find the **intl** extension in the same repository.

see information provided by the yum command

```
yum info php-cli
```

While I heartily recommends to upgrade to a supported version (7.1+), if you want to keep 5.6, "[remi](https://rpms.remirepo.net/)" is the only repository which still provides this version (with security [backports](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/02/07/PHP-5.6-is-dead)).

To upgrade your installation (to latest 5.6.40 or any other version, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3), simply follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

With RPM, you never have to change php.ini to enable installed extension, each package provides its own configuration file (ex: `/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini`) which
enable it.

With proper provider, for any needed extension (ex xxx), a simple

```
yum install php-xxx
```

will install the package with this extension (package name may be different, as some packages provide various extensions).